# Firefox version affects selenium webdriver test cases. What is the reason?

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, nunit, automated-tests

I have updated my Firefox version from v31 to v32. When I created my test cases in .net using web-driver, it was running perfectly in Firefox version 31 but as soon as I have updated my version to 32 it stopped running. It only opens the browser and doesn't navigate to URL. To solve this issue I uninstalled the v32 and installed v31 and its working fine. But I want to run on latest version. 
Please advice. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium WebDriver versions and Firefox versions are tightly coupled.

You need to use a Selenuim WebDriver version which supports Firefox v32. Usually the latest Firefox version supported in a particular Selenium WebDriver release is mentioned in the CHANGELOG.

If memory serves me, I believe Firefox v32 is supported in Selenium 2.43.0